# SQL Server Backup to Azure Tool

Tags: sql, azure, database-backup

I downloaded and tried the Microsoft SQL Server Backup to Azure tool for SQL Server 2008. My goal was to get access to the backup compression functionality built into it. I have it configured to backup to a folder on the local computer (the same folder it backups to to normally.) Everything went smooth with the install and the setup. But when I try to backup a database to that folder, I get an error that the "Device cannot be found." If I turn off the Windows Backup To Azure service then I can backup to the folder without issue. So it appears that the tool is locking the folder and not allowing anything to access it.

I am running on a Windows 8 Professional 64 bit, with SQL Server 2008. I opened a bug with MS but haven't gotten any responses naturally. I am open to ideas from the community in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried redirecting to another folder for the backups? (so in the SQL Backup To Azure Tool Config) This has to do (if i remember correctly )with the persmissions on the backup folders and the SQL Server accounts associated with it

Comment: Yes, I did try to restore to a different folder monitored by the SQL Backup to Azure tool and I received the same errors. What was interesting though it, just for laughs, I just added Everybody as a user to the folder with full permissions, and now it works. At least I have a starting point now.